# How to download & serve youtube-dl mp3 (on the fly) to the user?

Tags: php, linux, youtube, youtube-dl

I need a way to download & convert youtube videos to mp3 on the fly. I mean without having the user wait till the file is downloaded on my server and then serve it.
I'm currently using the following function to download the mp3 file to my server.It takes the video link as a param and returns the downloaded file location. It also checks if the file is already downloaded and returns its location if yes.

```
function downloadMP3($videolink){
    parse_str( parse_url( $videolink, PHP_URL_QUERY ), $parms );
    $id = $parms['v'];
    $output = "download/".$id.".mp3";
    if (file_exists($output)) {
        return $output;
    }else {
        $descriptorspec = array(
            0 => array(
                "pipe",
                "r"
            ) , // stdin
            1 => array(
                "pipe",
                "w"
            ) , // stdout
            2 => array(
                "pipe",
                "w"
            ) , // stderr
        );
        $cmd = 'youtube-dl --extract-audio --audio-quality 0 --audio-format mp3 --output download/"'.$id.'.%(ext)s" '.$videolink;
        $process = proc_open($cmd, $descriptorspec, $pipes);
        $errors = stream_get_contents($pipes[2]);
        fclose($pipes[2]);
        $ret = proc_close($process);
        if ($errors) {
            //print($errors);
        }
        return $output;
    }
}
```

Now whenever the user tries to download a file, I simply get the link and pass it to the function and use the following code to serve the file :

```
$downloadpath = downloadMP3($videolink);
$song_name = "song";
header('X-Accel-Redirect: /' . $downloadpath);
header("Content-Type: audio/mpeg, audio/x-mpeg, audio/x-mpeg-3, audio/mpeg3");
header('Content-length: ' . filesize($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/".$downloadpath));
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$song_name.'.mp3"');
header('X-Pad: avoid browser bug');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
```

I've looked online and found that people use `youtube-dl -o - VIDEO_URL` with `passthru()` and it works to download videos but not mp3 files.
So does anyone have any idea how to accomplish that ?

Comment: YouTube does not serve mp3 files. What you are currently doing is downloading an audio file and recoding it to mp3.

Comment: Do you have `ffmpeg` (or the like) installed? The [docs](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#post-processing-options) say it is required when using `--extract-audio`

Comment: @dragonfirE Yes, I do.

Comment: @phihag so there's no way to achieve what I want to achieve?

Comment: That's not what I said. I just pointed out that you are currently not downloading an mp3, but an audio file (likely m4a or similar) and then recoding it. You could recode the file as you are downloading it.

Comment: @phihag so I could download the file in it's original audio format (m4a I think) and recode it at the same time and serve it to the user?

Comment: Yes that's possible. You'll have to do the recoding yourself though, or write  a patch for youtube-dl to recode on the fly.

Comment: @phihag that's a good idea, thanks for your help